# (The) TIF is (the) IRT analog of (the) CTS theory. To use or not to use definite articles?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I have no clue whether to use "the" or not in such academic examples. Is there a definite correct choice for these sentences?

1. (the) TIF is (the) IRT analog of (the) CTS theory.
2. It depends on the choice of (the) ability parameters and (the) number of ICCs.
3. They investigated the performance of (the) X technique.
4. It is a unique technique in (the) optimization of (the) RBF depths.

Comment: It all depends on the context and what each of those mean. Abbreviations can have many different expansions. Can you provide the intended expansions for all of those?

Comment: TIF: test information function. IRT: item response theory. CTS: classical true score. ICC: item characteristics curve RBF: radial basis function

Comment: I just used whatever that was in front of me and thought that it doesn't make any difference. I actually need explanations not just answers.

Comment: TLAs are proper names; as with proper names, each has its own article usages that must be learned individually.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that if it is a specific thing then use 'the'. If generic then no 'the'

So it should be:

> The TIF (the function) is 
>   the IRT analog  (it is a particular *analog*)
>   of CTS theory. (A theory is generic)

2,3,4 all take 'the'.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Now I'm wondering why a theory is generic and a function is not.

Comment: In general, theories aren't always generic. We say "the theory of relativity" and not "theory of relativity". But usually, when a modifier precedes "theory", we drop the article. No idea why; part of it (when things are on the boundary of genericness like theories) is just arbitrary.

Comment: Yeah, you can take it or leave it with "the" ahead of "CTS".  The judgment is based in part on your appreciation of the terms, so it's impossible to give a general rule.

Answer (score -2):

1) Leave out the first "the"; keep the others.

2) Leave out the first "the"; keep the latter one  (and if you get to *choose* the number of ICCs, the latter "the" should be **of the**)

3) Keep the "the" before "X" (assuming X is a proper noun, capitalized; if not, there might be multiple "x" techniques, in which case you would say "*an* x technique")

4) Keep the first "the"; leave out the second "the"  (but I'm queasy about "unique technique **in** the optimization of...".  I'd feel better about "unique technique **for optimizing**... —maybe just because it's more straightforward)

Comment: Thank you, but It's really confusing. can you explain the reasons for your choices? (esp leaving out the first "the" in number 2)
I actually chose the first one from a book written by a native speaker. The original sentence was: The TIF is the IRT analog of CTS theory reliability and the standard error of measurement.

Comment: I meant the first parenthesized "the", not the first one. I can't explain linguistically why "choice of ability parameters" does not require "the" before "ability". Maybe someone else can.